# SQL DDL address must contain

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

How do i write a contraint for an address so it contains both a street address and a number? No need to handle addresses that contain apartment number or floor level. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain "stress address" ?

Comment: You can use NOT NULL or CHECK constraints. Exact syntax dependent on yours RDBMS

Comment: Show us some sample addresses of both types, an tell us if each one is valid or not. (Use formatted text, not images.)

Comment: What's your RDBMS?

Comment: What kind of sql are you using ? mySQL, sql server etc???

Comment: I'm using mySQL @Kendle

Comment: @sergey how would you use the check constraint here?

Comment: @luuk sorry typo.. meant street address

Comment: tag `mysql` added.  @KalbasaKalba: you could have done that yourself, using [edit]

Comment: @jarlh it just has to contain both characters and letters.. like this is not valid: streethall.. this is valid: streethall 51

Comment: Other countries have "number streetname", e.g. "51 streethall"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where can use a **CHECK** constraint with **RLIKE** and a ***regular expression***.
Here we have simply said that there must be a number followed by one or more words with hyphens and underscores allowed.
NB mySQL only enforces this in more recent version. Check this trial script in your version to see whether it works. If it is not enforced the only solution is a trigger **ON INSERT**

> ```
> create table user(
>   name varchar(25),
>   adresse varchar(25) check (adresse rlike '[0-9]+ [- a-zA-Z]+')
>   );
> ```

> ```
> insert into user values ('Boris', '10 Downing Street');
> ```

> ```
> insert into user values ('Poutin','The Kremlin');
> ```
>
> ```
> Check constraint 'user_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f7844cd4c3230dfbc26bbc336a174d3)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in a CHECK constraint:

```
check(street_address RLIKE'^[0-9]*[[:space:]].*$')
```

Or whatever makes sense for your column